# curl_easy_perform fail: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL when calling from Swift

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, curl

I am currently added a whole Objective-C project into Swift project. When I run only Objective-C project independently it works just fine, but when I call the Objective-C project from the swift I am getting this error.

```
[error] curl_easy_perform fail: URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

I don't have the access to the internal code of the framework.

Because of this I am unable to get any data from the API as I don't have the direct access to the API.

> And I am also having error "vector file not found" when I want to call a framework header from the swift

Comment: You have a `C library` so you can call this library with `#include yourLibrary`

Comment: All the libraries are called from the Objective-C project i don't have control over this.

Comment: If it works using Objective-C only, without Swift, I'd say that URL probably gets corrupted when passed from Swift to Objective-C code.  BTW, how do you pass that URL from Swift to Objective-C?  Or how do you pass the things the URL is built from in Objective-C code?

I also think there is C++ code involved here, `vector` must be referring to the well known header from C++ standard lib.  I added the C++ tag to your question.